# Cell colors changes on mouse-hover without effecting the text color

Tags: javascript, html, colors, styles

I want a table which each cell have different colours, which on mouse hover changes to a particular colour specified, without effecting the colour of text. Is it possible without JavaScript?
My simple table with three cell with different colours are

```
<table>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="red">Red</td>
<td bgcolor="blue">Blue</td>
<td bgcolor="green">Green</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Rederring the text colour should have no effect on any of the cell. I want this with simple scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .td_hover { background-color: white; }
        .td_hover:hover { background-color: yellow; }
        .bg_red { background-color: red; }
        .bg_blue { background-color: blue; }
        .bg_green { background-color: green; }
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="td_hover bg_red">Red</td>
        <td class="td_hover bg_blue">Blue</td>
        <td class="td_hover bg_greed">Green</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using CSS instead of decade-old `bgcolor` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

add a class (for my example "tablecell"), and remove bgcolor.

CSS-way:

```
.tablecell:hover {
    background-color:#000000; // Put color you want it to be on hover here.
}
.tablecell {
    background-color:#FF0000; // Put color you wan tit to be on not-hover here (optional)
}
```

Javascript-way:

```
myElement.addEventListener("onmouseover", mouseIn);
myElement.addEventListener("onmouseout", mouseOut);

function mouseIn() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
}

function mouseOut() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
}
```

jQuery way:

```
$(".tablecell").on("hover", mouseIn, mouseOut); // functions above
```